# What is 502 BAD GATE WAY nginx/1.4.6(Ubuntu)

Tags: error-handling

How and why do I get this error? I have a Boost LG and I've never used nginx or Ubuntu or even heard of them until recently. Is someone accessing or running these in my phone? Please help and thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

**When you will find 502 Bad Gateway error :**

Nginx running as proxy for Apache web server.

Nginx running with PHP-FPM daemon.

Nginx running with other services as gateway.

Bad buffering/timeout configuration.

**Solutions :**

**Other quick solutions for 502 Bad Gateway error:**

1) Increase buffer and timeouts inside http block:

```
http {
...
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
...
}
```

2) Ensure your php-fpm service is listening according to what you’ve configured in nginx, it can be either this two options:

Edit `www.conf` file (in CentOS it is located at /etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf and try with one of this two options:

```
listen = /var/run/php5-fpm.sock
or

listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
```

After that, just restart the php-fpm service.

3) Disable APC Cache if used, instead try Xcache, apc can cause this kind of issues under particular enviroments causing segmentation faults.

4)  I recently found another cause of 502 Bad Gateway error, check it out here: `php5-fpm.sock failed (13: Permission denied)` error

Comment: Ok i have no idea what any of that means but thank you for your time responding...ive never heard of or used either ngin

Comment: nginx or ubuntu...how is it in my android . is someone using them in my phone or accessing remotely. Does it mean im hacked? Thanks again

Comment: @RB2002 are you accessing a site? if yes then it could be a timeout configuration.

Comment: Yes accessing a site, mainly sites about trying to figure u

Comment: @RB2002, so it's basically the hosting site that has these errors. is it all the sites or specific one?

Comment: Sorry touch screen acting wierd

Comment: I belive it was chrome//urls when i click on certain urls like chrome flags or dns or network

Comment: @RB2002, then it could be your wifi connection if you're using it.. because slow connection to get the data from site will revoke in timeout session .
basically nobody could help your android device unless you've a malware in it.

Comment: Sorry and i appreciate your patience, this stuff is like a foreign languge. I dont know how to ask or answer efficiently or effectively. Also it happens when i try to google certain things that i find in my phone.for example some wierd hidden files that ive never seen or something from my system logs that i dont understand

Comment: @RB2002, is it a hidden extension or just a tmp file?

Comment: For your time, im not convinced that someone isnt accessing my account but i will keep trying to figure this out i left my phone over nite at neighbors by accident and every since then its like someone is sending commands via shell or accessing my phone i ran malwarebytes but it says im good to go so ya. Thanks again and cheers

Comment: Hidden extension